# Mathf.MoveTowards(z, 2f, Time.deltaTime) does not work. Where z is float z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical")

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

`Mathf.MoveTowards(z, 2f, Time.deltaTime)` does not work. Where `z` is

```
float z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
```

However, `Mathf.MoveTowards(z, 1f, Time.deltaTime)` works normally and the number smoothly increases from 0 to 1.
But here the maximum suddenly becomes 1.003.

I tried multiplying `z` by 2, I tried putting another value instead of `deltaTime`, but in this case the transition was instantaneous.

Comment: Welcome, please post a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), the shortest *complete* code that shows why you think that a well-tested library function "does not work". May I suggest you take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Do not use `C` tag on `C#` questions

Comment: floats a considerably less precise